# get the current time until next repeat with rxjs repeat

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-observables

I have an angular app using rxjs to hit an api endpoint every 10 seconds for updates and stops after 10 times.  It's working fine:

```
public checkAPI(): Observable<MyData> {
  return this.http
    .get<MyData>(this.dataUrl)
    .pipe(
      repeat( { delay: this.repeatInterval}),
      map( data => {
        // do some stuff 
        this.x++;
      }),
      takeWhile( () => {
        this.x < 10;
      })
    );
}
```

What I'd like to be able to do is know how long until it repeats again so I can put up a progress bar to show the user something like 'checking the api in N seconds'.  The thing I've thought of is that right before I do `this.checkAPI().subscribe( () => {});` to a `window.setInterval( () => {}, this.repeatInterval / 100);` so that the interval fires every 1% of the repeatInterval and track it that way.  But it isn't a perfect match.  Is there anything built into rxjs I could  use and haven't found yet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably several ways to achieve this. One that is in my mind at first glance can be something like:

```
const repeatWhen$ = switchMap(() => {
  return interval(1000)
    .pipe(
      // Map to get values such as 10, 9, 8, 7...
      map(i => 10 - i),
      // Show only values greater than 0 since api call can last 
      // sometimes longer (and you will get negative value 
      // because interval continues to tick)
      filter(i => i > 0),
      // Update ui to show seconds until reload
      tap(i => console.log('Reloading in:', i)),
      // 1000ms*10 = 10seconds is a repeat period
      // So when the buffer is full (on each 10seconds in our case)
     // it will emit value to outer stream, therefore repeat outer stream
      bufferCount(10)
    );
});

of(1).pipe(delay(5000))
  .pipe(
    repeatWhen((complete) => complete.pipe(repeatWhen$)
    )).subscribe(() => {
  console.log('result from outer stream');
});

// Ofc you can put this in your example (put this.http.get<MyData>(this.dataUrl) instead of of(1))
```

Comment: That's kind of what I was afraid of.  I was hoping to have only one loop instead of two and just capture the timing feature.  I suppose another way would be to loop every second, keeping track of how many, and then make the actual api call if time % 10 === 0.

Comment: But here you have only one "loop" and its interval...